# How to retrieve matched data from mysql table text datatype?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-json

I have one query to build to get matched data from table having value as text in json format.

```
CREATE TABLE `post_sender_detail` (
  `version_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subject` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'JSON of tags details',
  PRIMARY KEY (`version_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Values stored like this

| version_id | subject | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 83 | test sftp new series | {"1":"Two2","2":"Three 3","7":"one1"} |
| 82 | This is testing of seedlist | {"31":"one1","32":"Two2"} |
| 81 | non-amp test 001 | NULL |
| 80 | non-amp test 001 | NULL |

I want some query like

```
select * from post_sender_detail where tags match the key as 31;
```

And get the result like

| version_id | subject | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 82 | This is testing of seedlist | {"31":"one1","32":"Two2"} |

My DB version

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| innodb_version | 10.4.7 |
| protocol_version | 107 |
| version | 10.4.7-MariaDB-1:10.4.7+maria~bionic-log7 |

I tried my way but not getting something to get the desired result. Can you guys help here and let me know if there is any way to get it from MYSQL query?

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware MySQL 5.7 and later versions now have a [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) and a collection of [builtin JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html)? And Stack Overflow has hundreds of questions about using [JSON in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-json) which probably include answers to most of your questions?

Comment: ```WHERE 31 MEMBER OF JSON_KEYS(tags)```

Comment: @BillKarwin yes I have check that but that not working for me that's why I posted here.
this is existing table structure which is being used, I can't change this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @akina you can use `JSON_KEYS` to returns the keys from a JSON as array, and [`MEMBER OF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) to check if a value is an element of an array :

```
SELECT *
FROM post_sender_detail
WHERE '31' MEMBER OF( JSON_KEYS(CAST(tags AS JSON)))
```

Since you are using mariadb 10.4.7 then you can simply do :

```
select *
from post_sender_detail
where tags like '%"31":%'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JEpxQrBT)

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MEMBER OF( JSON_KEYS(CAST(tags AS JSON)))' at line 1.

JSON not supported I guess.

Comment: I check by changing the mysql version in your demo link as well getting the same error.

Comment: thanks second answer working as of now.